# UIRefreshControl EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to implement UIRefreshControl in a UIViewController. I can't use UITableViewController because the tableView is just one segment of my viewController.

In most cases this workaround works like charm. But sometimes (random occurrence) the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl * refCon = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refCon addTarget:self selector:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [tableView addSubView:refCon];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [NSThred detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doRefresh:) toTarget:self withObject:sender];
}

- (void)doRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [self checkUpdate];
    [self loadData];
    [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're invoking `-endRefreshing` on a background thread.  Don't do that.

And also, adding a `UIRefreshControl` directly as a subview of `UITableView` is not guaranteed to work.  You should be using a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Calling it on the main thread solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The first you put a tag at UIRefreshControl

```
UIRefreshControl * refCon = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refCon addTarget:self selector:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];
refCon.tag = 101 //for example
[tableView addSubView:refCon];
```

When the tableView finish of reload then you put:

```
UIRefreshControl *getRefreshControl = (UIRefreshControl*)[self.tablaPildoras viewWithTag:101];
[getRefreshControl endRefreshing];
```